# How to Implement Odata API without Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, odata, asp.net-web-api2, ienumerable

I have created OData Controller having method which returning list of data from service, Instead of service IEnumarable data. I need to return IQueryable or IEnurable data from SQL Query. I have simple SQL Data Adapeter and SQL Command Code structure in core logic.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the linq extension .AsQueryable() to convert your collection of items.
2. You can also accept a `queryOptions` object in your controller action and parse out items to use in your sql query.

   ```
   [EnableQuery]
   public async Task<IQueryable<Tool>> Get(ODataQueryOptions<Tool> queryOptions)
   {
       return await da.GetTools(queryOptions);
   }
   ```

An explanation of the QueryOptions can be found here http://www.ben-morris.com/parsing-odata-queries-decoupled-data-entities-webapi/

Comment: Is it possible to implement without inheriting from ODataController?

Comment: @MaulikModi I believe it will work with just a Web API controller